# which ssl certificate is the right one for aws elastic load blancer and cloudfront? ssl certificate compatibility

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Can I use any ssl certificate for aws services? Are there any prerequiries?

There isn't any kind of aws ssl certificate compatibility list. Does any certificate work for cloudfront (sni support) and  elastic load balancer. Do I have to get an special certificate or can I just use any? Are there any relevant differences between certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the documentation [1] that discusses the requirements/limits.  The big difference is for cloudfront, you need set your path to /cloudfront/.

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#cnames-and-https-requirements